# asp.net MVC: how to get the previous action name

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I　can get the current action name by using the following code

```
var currentActionName = ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
```

but is it possible to get the previous action name as well?

Comment: Could you explain why would you need this? What is your scenario? Maybe there's a better solution to your problem.

Comment: @Daoming Yang Do you need this to create a return URL or something?  If so you could just use the referrer in the request.

Comment: I want an action to do many different tasks based on the previous URL (pass action name into the switch statement). I do not want to create many action methods which could be difficult to maintain.

Comment: -1 for not closing the question

Comment: @Kelsey, the if the referral was caused by something like an auth decoration, the referrer ends up being null :/

Answer (score 0):

Why not saving it in a session variable?

Try this:

```
Session["lastAction"] = Session["actualAction"];
Session["actualAction"] = ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
```

Comment: Better approach may be to use TempData as it's cleared each time it is read.